# How to convert .pem file into .byok file format

Tags: azure, openssl, azure-keyvault

I want to import the own key in Azure key vault using PowerShell. For that I need to convert the existing .pem file into .byok format. How to convert .pem file into .byok file format?

Comment: Does this site contain what you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/hsm-protected-keys the method seems to differ based on what your source HSM is

Comment: Yes looking for the same, but its a confusing document from Microsoft, the steps are tricky and difficult to implement. Actually I want to import .pem file using PowerShell or ARM template into Azure Key Vault for that the document says to convert the .pem to .byok which is very tedious process. Is there any way to directly import .pem file in Key section of Azure Key Vault using PowerShell or ARM template. From the Azure portal it works fine but Im looking for Automation.